# How do I pull Docker images from the Tutum private registry with Amazon ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecs, tutum

I am trying to set up an [Amazon ECS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html) deployment which employs an image from the [Tutum](http://tutum.co/) private Docker registry. Tutum being private, it requires authenticating obviously.

As per [the ECS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html), I've modified the file '/etc/ecs/ecs.config' on the EC2 instance to contain the correct authentication credentials for Tutum:

```
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA={"tutum.co":{"auth":"<auth-string>","email":"<my-email>"}}
```

The auth string is a Base64 encoding of my Tutum credentials: `'<username>:<password>'`.

However, when I try to run the corresponding ECS task, it fails with this message: *CannotPullContainerError: Authentication is required*.

How do I properly configure ECS to authenticate against the Tutum registry, so I can successfully pull images from there?

Comment: Posting the same question hope you will help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052334/private-docker-registry-authentication-in-aws-ecs-optimized-ami-is-not-successfu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if what it took was to reboot the EC2 instance, so that the settings in '/etc/ecs/ecs.config' were applied.